# What does this mean by variable define in C

Tags: c, variables

can you guys tell me, what does this mean in C?

```
 #define Privileged_Data
 Privileged_Data static int dVariable
```

Is it specific meaningful for Compiler to address variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a macro `Privileged_Data` doing nothing. The compiler will not even see it after the preprocessor pass.

It's probably a readability or company standards decision to tag some variables like this.

Comment: maybe a macro to be able to insert `volatile` or not.

Comment: Maybe in some configuration OP didn't show, perhaps.

Comment: A good example of this practice is Microsoft's SAL (Source Code Annotiation Language), where they mark the input parameters as `_In_` and the output as `_Out_`

Comment: @Vect0rZ inout is cool to differentiate from out when passing a pointer to some data. for in and out you can use `const` pointer or not.

Answer (score 2):

A preprocessor macro can be defined without an associated value.  When that is the case, the macro is substituted with nothing after preprocessing.

So given this:

```
#define Privileged_Data
```

Then this:

```
Privileged_Data static int dVariable
```

Becomes this after preprocessing:

```
static int dVariable
```

So this particular macro has no effect on the program, and was probably put in place for documentation purposes.

Comment: Q: Is this considered good practise? To me as an old-timer C guy, it seems like abuse of a language feature.

Comment: @GermanNerd I would tend to agree.  There are other ways to document code.

Comment: Nice to hear that. And thank you for your answer; initially this (ab)use of the #define directive had me really puzzled - like 'Is that something new in c99/c11/cxx....?'